# Promoting Users to Local Administrators

Tags: windows-xp

Is it possible to promote several users to local administrators in one easy process? I know I can manually add them to the Local Administrators group but is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to use a script.

Presuming the users already exist on your system there is one at this site that should pretty much be perfect for your needs:
http://computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine112.htm

you will have to change the Machine Name and make sure you read the notes carefully